# Java file replication

Tags: java

I have a java application that write some things on local disk and I need to have a replica in a remote system.
Is there any usable tool for it?

Answer (score 2):

[rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Java solution, than the open source project **[SyncDir](http://syncdir.sourceforge.net/)** might help.
You can use it manually or in a script, or directly in your Java program using it's API.

Of course there are many other solutions, but what you might be interested in, besides the simplicity of the API (or it's usage + documentation) might be the performance too (if you need to sync huge amount of files).

In this case, a performance comparison of the various libraries is necessary, so you need to design your code to easily be able switch between sync libraries.